# Why does Scipy have different functions ‘signal.convolve2d’ and ‘signal.correlate2d’?

Tags: python, scipy, signals

When does ‘signal.convolve2d’ and ‘signal.correlate2d’ (with identical arguments) produce different results?

I just started using Scipy, and I can not determine the difference of utilizing signal.correlate2d(array,filter,'same') and signal.convolve2d(array,filter,'same'), while the results are identical in all of the cases that I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do because they are actually perform different task

```
signal.convolve2d() #does convolving
signal.correlate2d() #does just cross-correlation
```

Convolving is performing cross-correlation with a filter that as been mirrored horizontally and vertically.

Cross-correlation is what is usually done in deep learning where you do the multiplication using your filter as it is.

For nonsymmetric filters, the result is different. Though, for symmetric filters, you can not observe any difference in the usage of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at their code.  They look almost identical, except one uses:

```
sigtools._convolve2d(in1, in2.conj(), 0, val, bval, fillvalue)
```

and the other:

```
sigtools._convolve2d(in1, in2, 1, val, bval, fillvalue)
```

Presumably you know enough about convolving to explain the difference, right?

Typically the answers for `why this code` involve a history, that can go back years.  Different people write different bits of code, they get merged, and sometimes minor differences remain just for the sake of backward compatibility.  It's easier to keep a couple similar versions than to tell users, 'you have to switch'.